# creating custom xtype using extjs for a dialog in aem

Tags: extjs, aem, custom-widgets

I am trying to create a new question module. Requirements:
**True or False** - two multifields for options either true or false
**Single Option** - as many options as user wants (radio button to choose one option).
**Multiple choice Q** - as many options as user wants (check box format to choose multiple options).
I have tried creating a dialog structure (refer image),please suggest a way to create a custom xtype to link the question type radio button to the no. of options provided.

[image: dialog image]

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please post the current code of the dialog. Tutorials on custom xtypes are simple enough to google. Have you tried following this tutorial https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-custom-xtype.html ?